# codeIgniter base url issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, mod-rewrite

Hi i am new in codeigniter, having trouble with link formation. In my page i have link to another page same to `<a href = "<?php base_url('feed');?>"><li>Feed Page</li></a>`
here feed is one of my controller . But the link is showing to me as            `http://localhost/BusinessPad/localhost/BusinessPad/feed`    ---that  actually doesn't exists. Can't understand how this happen. I have make $config['index_page'] = ''; and add a .htaccess file.

Comment: I think all of this answer is right. But my case is different if i remain <a href = " "><li>Feed Page</li></a>....the link set as base url automatically. i mean the link show as http://localhost/BusinessPad/   and if i put value of href . that value added after http://localhost/BusinessPad/ ...then it shown as http://localhost/BusinessPad/localhost/BusinessPad/feed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check for value you have assigned to `base_url` in you `config.php` file ,try [site_url()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html), change:

```
<?php base_url('feed');?>
```

to

```
<?php echo site_url('feed'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own  tag and insert a url in the href like this

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function/uri') ?>">Link</a>
```

Or if you want to helper

you can use the URL helper this way to generate an  tag

```
anchor(uri segments, text, attributes)
```

So... to use it...

```
<?php echo anchor('controller/function/uri', 'Link', 'class="link-class"') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:-

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('feed');?>">Link</a>
```

or

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'feed';?>">Link</a>
```

or

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/feed';?>">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use this way
<a href = "<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/feed">Feed Page</a>
or 
<a href = "<?= base_url() ;?>/index.php/feed">Feed Page</a>
```